# Code dump on page before JS redirect kicks in

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I have a `window.location.href` redirect in the `<head>` of a page. which happens when a certain condition is met and the user is redirected to a similar page, which uses the same header and footer templates (so the same JS code is there again - this may be important to possible solutions)

Sometimes, for a split second, just before the physical redirect kicks in, I see a bunch of code dumped in the browser window. This happens in about 1/20 times for me. For some other people I've asked, it happens more often.

Is this the rest of the JS on the page being dumped there as it breaks out before being fully parsed or...? I imagine there is a couple of hundred milliseconds of time in which the browser continues parsing the rest of the page after the redirect line. How would I prevent this code from showing on the page?

Comment: Any progress on your problem?

Comment: No resolution yet (for the current state of the code). Your suggestion might work, I don't know, but I don't want to wait for body to be available. Redirect needs to happen as soon as possible :)

Comment: Ah, then let me know, I can't guess these things :) You can instead set a `showBody` variable to 'true` and put a second script tag at the body which does `if(showBody) document.body.style.display = "block";`

Comment: The problem "resolved itself" in that I can no longer get it reproduced. This displeases me. I'll have to wait until it shows its face again to test. I'll accept the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on keeping the redirect on the client side - You can set the body to `display:none` , and then in the `else` branch of your conditional in JavaScript - show it:

CSS

```
body{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
if(someCondition){
    location.hred = "http://othersite";
} else {
    document.body.style.display = "block";
}
```

Note that this has the disadvantage of showing a blank page to people who don't have JS enabled, so you might want to do it for a less 'drastic' tag than `<body>`.